# Wix: How to specify a pre-installation detection

Tags: windows, wix

I‘m reading wix’s tutorial and manuals, and trying to figure out how to apply a pre-installation detection, say detecting if Visual Studio 2012 and Update 2 has been installed on the machine.

the following is a wix source code, but I'm not sure whether the registry keys are prerequisite for detection.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" xmlns:dd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2005/01/dd">
<!-- Detection keys fragment. -->
<Fragment>
    <!-- TARGETDIR should be set by a type 51 CA to the root installation location for all products. -->
    <DirectoryRef Id="TARGETDIR">
        <!-- Use all variables in the full key path for the auto-generated GUID, 
             including LANG, since [ProductName] is lang-specific. 
        -->
        <Component Id="Detection_Keys_Reg" Guid="$(autoguid.ComponentGuid(Detection_Keys_Reg,$(var.ProductFamily),$(var.ProductEdition),$(var.VSRegVer),$(var.Lang)))">
            <RegistryKey Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\$(var.VSRegVer)\Setup\[ProductName]">
                <RegistryValue Id="Detection_Keys_RegKey_1" Name="InstallSuccess" Type="integer" Value="1" KeyPath="yes" />
                <RegistryValue Id="Detection_Keys_RegKey_2" Name="SrcPath" Type="string" Value="[SourceDir]" />
            </RegistryKey>
        </Component>
    </DirectoryRef>
    <Feature Id="Detection_Keys" Absent="disallow" AllowAdvertise="no" Description="Used to detect product installation" Display="hidden" Level="1" InstallDefault="local" Title="Detection" TypicalDefault="install">
        <ComponentRef Id="Detection_Keys_Reg" />
        <dd:ExtensionData FeatureGuid="67DC7E25-1836-42AA-A0F8-6E85528D6986" InstallDirectory="TARGETDIR" AllowRunFromSource="no" FeatureGFN="DetectionKeys">Detection Keys</dd:ExtensionData>
    </Feature>
</Fragment>
```

The two registry keys in folder

"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0_Config\Setup\Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2012\"

do exist (but not in HKLM) after my installing VS2012. I don't understand some of the tags (still reading the manual)

so the questions are:
1. Is this for detection?  2. How do I write some pop up messages when the required software does not exist.

Can you provide some typical samples for this purpose?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a `Condition` element within your `Product` element. Quoting from the WiX documentation of the condition element: Under a Fragment or Product element, the condition becomes a LaunchCondition entry.

In case the condition fails, the installation will abort, showing the message you want it to show.

A very simple example:

```
  <Condition Message="Minimum 1 GB of RAM required. Aborting installation.">
    <![CDATA[Installed OR PhysicalMemory >= 1024]]>
  </Condition>
```

In case you want to use a registry key, set a property using the `RegistrySearch` element as in:

```
  <Property Id="TEST">
    <RegistrySearch Id="TestRegKey"
                    Root="HKLM"
                    Key="Software\TestKey"
                    Name="Version"
                    Type="raw" />
  </Property>
```

Now you can use this property within the inner text of the Condition.

Comment: yes, this is almost what I want, but one thing I don't understand is that why the sample code in my question is commented as a key detection? It really seems like writing some information into the registry.

Comment: It does seem like it is setting a registry key. maybe some property in the Feature element for that Component does something, but I couldn't see anything obvious. You can try reading up the docs and see if it helps..

Answer (score 1):

1.Registry key to use for VS/Update Detection

You can use below registry for detection purpose, This has value UpdatedVersion=  
CurrentBuildNumber=11.0.60315 For VSUpdate2

Registry key
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\DevDiv\vs\Servicing\12.0\professional

2.If your intention is to search for VSUpdate2 you need to use [registrysearch](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/wix_xsd_registrysearch.htm) Tag, Which will search the value for you. Once you have updated value you can have logic of custom pop up in your Managed UX

Comment: In fact my main purpose is to write code to handle the general process of pre-installation detection and how to react when one condition is false. I saw a few registrysearch Tags before, I'll read more on it.

Comment: this really helped. I didn't know the difference between 32 and 64 bit machines when checking the registry key manually. thanks.